# Trouble after Resetting Password and Security Token

Tags: login-errors, security-token, force.com-explorer

I reset my password, and then my security token.

But my Mule connector won't connect, and "Force.com Explorer (Beta)" says `Login failed: INVALID_LOGIN: Invalid username, password, security token; or user locked out.`

I know that for Explorer it's password + token, I did that carefully.  And carefully changed the connector's settings.

Things I've tried:

- Logged out and logged back in to the main website with the new password.
- Tried the Reset Security Token again
- Waited a while (20 mins) after the email to give SF a chance to update its caches or whatever
- Fully exited Explorer and went back in
- The account isn't locked, I'm able to login
- Tried not to test too many times in a row, so as to not lock the account
- I'm typing the password carefully and pasting the token, no extra spaces, etc.

Is there some known issue with password or token resets?  Some magic length of time?

Comment: Were you able to resolve the issue?

Comment: @highfive yes, thanks for checking, so I posted the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If your token gets reset often you can also whitelist your IP by going to

Security Controls -> Session Managment and get your IP ->Then go to Network Access and Add your IP in there`

It gets annoying when your trying to manage your security keys with Force.com explorer, and a IDE esp it changes often..

[This will also help you](http://starrforce.com/2013/10/whitelisting-your-ip-address-in-salesforce/).

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I was "off by one" in the emails they were sending me with new tokens, some type of delay, and I they sent one more than I expected, so I hadn't noticed the delay.